# Import source code: Could not install Gradle distribution

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship, spring-tools-4

**Gradle**

```
michael@michael:~$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Java**
michael@michael:~$ java -version
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14

**Spring Tool Suite 4 (an Eclipse derivative)**

```
Version: 4.6.0.RELEASE
```

**Buildship**
Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle 3.1.4.v20200326-1743    org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship

I've downloaded a code samples for a book.

Then:

File -> Import -> Existing Gradle Project.

When I import, I override workspace settings:
 1. Gradle version = 6.3
 2. Gradle user home = /opt/gradle/gradle-6.3/bin
 3. Java home = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin

The same as described above:

[image]

The problem:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-bin.zip'.
Could not create parent directory for lock file /opt/gradle/gradle-6.3/bin/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.3-bin/8tpu6egwsccjzp10c1jckl0rx/gradle-6.3-bin.zip.lck    beginning-spring-5      line 0  Gradle Error Marker
```

The same as a picture:

[image]

Well, STS seems to be trying to install Gradle.

Could you help me understand what is going on and help cope with this.
If I do everything wrongly, please help me just import the source code.

Comment: Since the question is around importing Gradle projects, I added the `buildship` tag to it, since that is the Gradle integration for Eclipse that is used in here.

Comment: Your user wouldn't, and probably shouldn't, have write access to `/opt/gradle/`. Pick a location under your home directory.